# A complex structure: Xが～するYについて、～する者は

Tags: parsing, reading-comprehension, は-and-が, subordinate-clauses, modification

So I'm reading the One Punch Man manga to learn some vocabulary. I have the Portuguese translation and I compare it with my translation.

But I read something that I think is wrong in the Portuguese translation or I lost the Japanese way of expression:

A little context. So this guy is a genius and everyone praises him.

The next text is:

> しかし彼が　常日頃吐き出す思想について　認める者は誰一人いなかった。

I translated like "he doesn't care about people ideas."

The Portuguese translation is like "people don't agree with his ideas."

I'm lost.

Comment: I am a little confused with your question. Are you trying to find out why the official translation is different from yours? Can you show your parsing so we can understand how you're interpreting?

Comment: Literally, I think it's like, 'However, there's never anybody who acknowledges the ideas he spews.'

Comment: Leave out the immediate beginning, middle, and some of the end of the sentence, and you have 「彼が認める者はない」= "There is no one who acknowledges him." The rest of the sentence merely provides context for that main idea. Complicated sentences are usually best handled by finding the words next to the main sentence particles, like は、が、を.

Comment: @archaephyrryx 「彼が認める者はない」means 'there's nobody he acknowledges'. The sentence is parsed 「しかし・彼が常日頃吐き出す思想について・認める者は・誰一人いなかった」。

Comment: @archaephyrryx かれが認める者はない would be "there's no one he acknowledges". i think you mean 彼を or better would be 彼の思想を認める者はない。

Comment: You are absolutely right. I left out too much, and flubbed the translation. It should be 「彼[の]思想[を]認める人はない」, which translates properly to "There is no one who acknowledges his thoughts."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> しかし彼が　常日頃吐き出す思想について　認める者は誰一人いなかった。
>   The portuguese translation is like "people doesn't agree with his ideas"

The translation is correct.

> I translated like "he doens't care about people ideas"

It's

> しかし［《**彼が** {常日頃} **吐き出す**》思想について］**認める 者は** {誰一人} **いなかった**。

The main clause is 認めるものは誰一人いなかった。

彼が常日頃吐き出す思想について is an adverbial phrase to 認める; and this 認める is an adjective to 者.

---

When you see **が**, try thinking of it as an ***alarm*** for you to know the existence of a ***subordinate clause*** or a modifying clause.

I can't generalize here, but at least I can tell you that *the sentence subject could be indicated later in the sentence with は*.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand. What are these { and [ meaning? Never Saw before.

Comment: They are just to show you how the sentence structure is. The particular selections are just for you. :)

Comment: `認める is an adjective...` ←「『認める』は **形容詞**です」てのはちょっと・・・。日本人の国語の授業でも外国人学習者向けの日本語授業でも、そうは教えませんよね・・　「認める」はどの辞書をひいても**動詞**ですから。。

Comment: いちいちadjectival phrase などと厳密に説明しなければいけないんですか？

Comment: 「いちいち」って…めんどくさいってことかいな。じゃ間違ったままにしときなはれ。無知をさらしてんの私じゃないし

Comment: もう少しみなさんが気持ちよく利用できるように配慮していただけると、みなさんが助かります。

Comment: `いちいち～～などと～～しなければいけないんですか？`が、`みなさんが気持ちよく利用できるように配慮` した発言だとは知りませんでしたw